# Computing an indefinite integral(2)

Tags: calculus

$$\int \sqrt{1- \sin(2x)}dx =?$$

**My attempt:**
$$\int \sqrt{1- \sin(2x)}dx = \int \sqrt{(\cos x - \sin x)^{2}} dx = \int|\cos x- \sin x| dx = ??$$

Comment: Break up the interval into regions where you have to integrate $\cos x-\sin x$, or $\sin x-\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

For real $a,|a|=+a$ if $a\ge0$  else $-a$

Now, $\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$

which will be $\ge0$  if $2n\pi\le\dfrac\pi4-x\le2n\pi+\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

Notice,  $$\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos x-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin x\right)=\sqrt 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)$$
but $\sin \theta\ge 0\iff 2k\pi\le \theta\le 2k\pi+\pi$
hence, solving the inequality

1. $$2k\pi\le \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\le 2k\pi+\pi$$
   $$ 2k\pi\le \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\implies x\leq -\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
2. $$\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\le 2k\pi+\pi\implies x\ge -\left(2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$$
   hence, we get
   $$\color{red}{|\cos x-\sin x|}=\cases{\color{blue}{\cos -\sin x}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \  \forall\ \ -\left(2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\le x\le -\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\ \color{blue}{-(\cos -\sin x)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall\ \ -\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\le x\le -\left(2k\pi-\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)}$$
   where, $\color{red}{k}$ is any integer